# Not able to get correct value using position in spinner

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I have created 2 spinners say city and location. I have saved city and location data in local database and fetch cities from local database and show them.

Now, my problem is this I have added "select city" position on 0th position of array list. When I select any city and run command to get location based on city then I get wrong locations based on position.

I am not able to get correct position.

// code

```
dumy = new Dumy(this);
cityAreaModelsList = dumy.getOnlyCities();
cityList = new ArrayList<String>();
cityList.add(0, "Select City");

for (int i = 0; i < cityAreaModelsList.size(); i++) {
    cityList.add(cityAreaModelsList.get(i).getCityName());
}
```

// spinner code

```
select_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Select City " );
        } else {
            cityId = (String)  cityAreaModelsList.get(position).getCityId();
            Log.e(TAG, "onItemSelected: "+cityId );
        }
    }
}
```

// say i have selected new delhi its city id is 1 but it gives me 2. Why? Please help

Answer (score 1):

because of position of adapter starting from 1 (only data part)

and cityAreaModelsList is accessing from 0;

try below code:

```
cityId = (String) cityAreaModelsList.get(position-1).getCityId();
```